# Using LaTeX and SVN on iPad

Tags: ipad, latex, subversion

I'm used to write technical documents with LaTeX and use SVN as version system.

I really would like to be able to do the same with my iPad.

**The first problem is found a good App for LaTeX**

I found some of them bu they are not cheap and I don't want to spend 8$ each one just for finding out the best one.  Does someone can point me to the best one from thee followings or other I don't know?

- [Tex Touch](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/tex-touch/id377627321?mt=8)
- [TeX Writer](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/tex-writer-latex-editor-compiler/id552717222?mt=8)
- [Texpad](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/texpad-latex-editor/id550419159?mt=8)

A good App should have the following features:

- Local compilation (there are some Apps which send data to a Server which returns the compiled PDF)
- Support for documents splitted in multiple files
- Support for images

**The second problem is found a good SVN client**

The SVN client should allow me to check out a project an do commits and updates.

Having a LaTeX Apps which allows me to open and edit the files downloaded with the SVN client would be already great.

Having a LaTeX App which integrates SVN support would be a dream.

Dis someone had the same problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Could you split this into two questions as very possible separate people can anser the latex and version control questions

Comment: @Mark, on the one side you are right, on the other side instead I would love to have both the features in the same App.

Comment: @Mark or at least a work-flow for using SVN ad LaTeX on my iPad. However the two features in my use case are strictly related. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, go to read tweets in Twitter under #texwriter. You can find a lot of this type of questions. Anyway I recommend TexWriter. You may find my writing useful [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393) where I mention my favourite apps and how I write LaTex in iPad -- confessing: I like to use Git instead of SVN, I use DropBox and my laptop for commiting -- I don't know yet any better way for this.

**TeXWriter: Tex -app with builtin compiler**

> It is the best app currently in the market although buggy but getting better. I have tested all of them and Texpad and Tex Touch are more slow/buggy -- and without the builtin compiler. TexWriter is the only app with the compiler builtin -- and you can find a growing community around it in Twitter and some [here](http://www.litchie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1345&start=0) -- we want to make it better!

**Use Git instead of SVN**

> Most cool things appear in Git such as Git-Annex [here](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/joeyh/git-annex-assistant-like-dropbox-but-with-your-own?ref=live). Instead of DropBox, this may be a promising candidate. I haven't tested it but it claimns to be some sort of replacement. For now on, you may want to use Git inside DropBox before getting Git-annex -working.

Comment: @TeXPad has long since had updates and also has a built-in compiler. Just leaving a comment to update this 3 year old post. `fontspec` for XeLaTeX is still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great SVN client. It is [iRepoEditor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/irepoeditor/id404799255?mt=8).

It allows us to check out, update and commit from SVN repositories and Dropbox folders.
It also provides a **basic** text editor and the possibility of open files in other Apps and then reimport them. It is not straight forward but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I have been using scribtex for some time now and am quite satisfied. It is on the web and you are given lots of space free. The editor is not too good but then, if you know enough of Latex, you can write the entire document in Evernote or Plain Text (both free apps for iPad) and then paste it in the scribtex editor and compile it to see the result. All these are free. Like you, I am also a bit skeptical about the paid apps and scribtex is working out quite well for me.

Comment: Thanks, however I asked for a completely local App.

Comment: Not local compilation -1, not meeting the requirement of the op.